# Defer all requests until database is connected

Tags: node.js, database, azure, asynchronous, restify

My [Restify](http://restify.com) server is dependent on a database connection which is established through an asynchronous function and a callback. I'm hosting it on Azure, where the server turns off after a period of inactivity, but when it wakes up, it restarts Node.js.

This is causing an error where a request wakes up the server, which crashes because the DB connection hasn't been established yet. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: I'm using the node-mssql module here: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that seems to work although I don't understand why:

You start by immediately calling any `use` functions in Restify and then later calling the `listen` function after the DB is connected. Here's an example:

```
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'Example',
});

server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.queryParser());

function initializeServer() {
    server.listen(80);
    console.log("The server is now active.");
}

var database = new sql.Connection(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        initializeServer();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a general setting named `Always On` of your Azure Web Apps. And by default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time, then your database connector will disconnect. And your modification makes sure that when your application is waked up to handle the requests, the database connector has been established.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why the request that wakes it isn't dropped. Since there technically is no server listening now until the DB is connected, is seems like the request should just return 500. But somehow the request is delayed until the server starts listening.

Comment: As Node.js application on Azure Web Apps are hosted via iisnode, it should be the iisnode feature.  Please refer to the **Process management** benefit at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki